# "Good to hear(read) from you"

Tags: phrases, sentence

I have noticed people use this sentence to reply to written mails but I often ask myself; why use "hear" when you "read" ?

Is it just a generally accepted phrase or people do use it wrongly ?

Comment: It is considered correct.  Saying "Hope to read from you soon" wouldn't exactly sound right, would it?

Answer (score 6):

That's what people say and a language doesn't have to follow any rules of logic - people use a certain word to mean something and that's correct. Everybody uses "hear" to mean

> **gain information, learn, to receive communication** - [**Merriam-Webster**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hear)

- **Good to hear from you.**
- **Hope to hear from you soon.**
- **I haven't heard from her for a long time.**

Answer (score 3):

People use "good to hear from you" or "hope to hear from you" instead of "good to read from you" or "hope to read from you" because sending (and receiving) letters, e-mails, and text messages is not the only communication method in the world. You receive a voice call and video call using your mobile phone, Skype, etc. In that case, you can't "read" from someone. That's why you use "hear" rather than "read" because it covers all of the communication methods you have.

In addtion, "[***Hear***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hear)" has the following meaning:

> (hear from) Be contacted by (someone), especially ***by letter*** or
>   telephone: ‘if you would like to join the committee, we would love to
>   hear from you’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

So you can't say it is wrong to use "hear from" in your example.

In the past, not many people had a proper education and illiteracy rate was rather high. When an illiterate person receives a letter, he can't read it. He has to "hear" the contents from someone who can read it on behalf of him. I think it is part of the reason the word "hear" has been used.

Comment: The funny thing is, this does not answer the question one bit. Dictionaries follow usage. So basically you merely just repeated the question right back at the OP. They *know* that "hear" has that meaning. Their question is, *why* does it have it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I don't think it is always true dictionaries follows usage. How long do you think our ancestors lived without proper dictionaries? How many words did you learn by looking up dictionaries especially those derived from Latin? Your logic doesn't work unless you learned to speak all those Latin words verbally from your parents or siblings. If he is asking for a word that is not listed in a dictionary, your logic might work, though.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I edited my answer to show more "why" part. Please take a look and if you still find it funny, please let me know. I will delete it.

Comment: @Rathony I am really amazed for your explanation of hearing part of a letter which escaped our attention. It is a fact. In some parts of the world a few decades ago , one has to traverse a great distance to get a letter read (heard)

Answer (score 2):

I have an ingenious explanation to offer. Among the 'verbs of perception' we depend mostly on 'see' and 'hear' to be informed about someone's well being. Perhaps long before the age of stage-coach (mode of sending a letter) or penny post,let alone the modern era of communicative explosions, the only dependable mode of knowing about someone's wellbeing was to hear from someone about the person of our interest, who happened to visit our place from the distant land of my acquaintance, relation or friend.

'HEAR' gains into prominance for the simple reason that we have no means of 'seeing'. Moreover, seeming is not like the seeming. So, depend on 'hear'.

The days of face to face interaction are long lost in oblivion. Letters come to replace it. But by that time, 'hear' has earned a permanent reputation in communicative English. Letters become the representative  figure of relations or friends. Through them we commune, we hear them speak.

Invention of telephone further reinforced this communicative usage of 'hear' with the present day dictionary meaning. We don't use 'good to read from you' for the simple reason that "reading" is a comparatively recent development in the evolution of languages and when you read, you read at the exclusion of your friends, where the comprehensive character of 'hear'is missing.

A word of worry. In this age of Skype, video calling and whats-app, hear would soon fall into abuse. We would begin to say — Good to see you, Good to hear you ("from " being struck off.)